# Comparision of numpy module array with list

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to compare numpy array with list....
Because i am new to python, i don't know about numpy array
I want to know the application of numpy array 
Please help out in understanding numpy array.

```
>>> from numpy import *
>>> res1 = []
>>> res2 = array([])
>>> if res1 == res2:
...    print 'hi'
... else:
...    print 'bye'
... 
bye

>>> res1 = [1]
>>> res2 = array([1])
>>> if res1 == res2:
...    print 'hi'
... else:
...    print 'bye'
... 
hi
>>> res1 = [1,2]
>>> res2 = array([1, 2])
>>> if res1 == res2:
...    print 'hi'
... else:
...    print 'bye'
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use    a.any() or a.all()
```

Any one please help why i am getting value error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comparison `res1 == res2` creates a new array of booleans, which represent an element-wise comparison of the list and array contents:

```
>>> res1 == res2
array([ True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

As the error message tells you, you cannot directly assign a truth value to an array, so you need to test whether `all` items are `True`:

```
>>> np.all(res1 == res2)
True
```

This only happens because your list and array are the same shape:

```
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = [3, 2]
>>> a == b
False
```

Note that I have used `import numpy as np` rather than `from numpy import *` - this means that I don't override e.g. the built-in `all` with `numpy`'s version.

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `numpy.array_equal(a1, a2)` for compare tow `numpy` array !

**True if two arrays have the same shape and elements, False otherwise.**

DEMO:

```
>>> np.array_equal(np.array([1, 2]), np.array([1, 2]))
True
>>> np.array_equal([1, 2], [1, 2, 3])
False
```